# How does OpenGL connect the vertices it's passed to

Tags: opengl

I keep reading in OpenGL intros that you pass your data as vertices to GPU and it connects them together. Say we want to draw a triangle then we pass this:

```
float vertices[] = {
     0.0f,  0.5f, // Vertex 1 (X, Y)
     0.5f, -0.5f, // Vertex 2 (X, Y)
    -0.5f, -0.5f  // Vertex 3 (X, Y)
};
```

My question is how does it know which dot to connect to which? Does it connect everything together if I pass in more vertices?

Comment: Read the documentation for the `glBegin` function.

Comment: There is no glBegin, seems outdated. Thats anther problem with this learning curve, everyone says stuff that's outdated.

Comment: @Josh: Outdated it may be, but you would have learned what you wanted to know by reading the `glBegin` documentation.  I'm not saying to actually call `glBegin` in your code, just understand what it says about vertex order.

Answer (score 1):

> Say we want to draw a triangle then we pass this: [...]

Not, this are just 3 vertices. The vertices define a triangle if you use a [Triangle primitive type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives). e.g. `GL_TRIANGLES`.

The [Primitive type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) which you pass to the draw call (e.g. [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml), [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml)) defines the shape of the mesh. There a primitive types for points, lines and triangles.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you have configured OpenGL to work. There are several ways that OpenGL allows you to describe the triangles you want to draw.

For instance, the simplest way is telling OpenGL your `vertices` array are triangles that each take 3 vertices. So the 4th vertex in the array would be the 1st vertex of the 2nd triangle, while the 5th vertex in the array would be the 2nd vertex of the 2nd triangle, and so on.

There are other ways to describe the triangles you want to draw, like using triangle strips or fans, using indexed arrays, etc.